# Выделение памяти под двумерный массив

Tags: массивы, память, c++

Работа с двумерным массивом. Код отрабатывает верно. Вот проблемный кусок. Что я делаю не так?

```
void delete_array(int **array, int row_count){
    for(int r=0; r<row_count; r++)
       delete[] array[r];
       delete [] array;
  }

int **create_array(int n,int m){
    int** array=new int*[m-1];
    for(int s=0;s<m;s++)
            array[s]=new int [1];
    return array;
 }

main(){
 int **array;
//Тут читаем n и m из файла
 array = create_array(n,m);
 delete_array(m);
}
```

Программулина вылетает. Компилятор не жалуется (GCC).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Конечно она будет вылетать. `delete_array` требует два параметра, а вы передаете один. То есть, как минимум нужно вызывать так

```
delete_array(array, m);
```

также очень странно, что gcc пропустил `main()`. Он что, жутко древний? или Вы компилируете не плюсовый код, а чистый с (хотя какой с. Там `new` есть)?

Вторая ошибка спряталась на видном месте. когда массив создается, то его первая размерность - `m-1`. А при удалении (да и при создании) проходим на один элемент больше. Так как выходим за пределы массива, то отсюдова и все проблемы.

Исправленный вариант

```
void delete_array(int **array, int row_count) {
    for(int r=0; r<row_count; r++)
        delete[] array[r];
    delete [] array;
}

int **create_array(int n,int m) {
    int** array=new int*[m];
    for(int s=0; s<m; s++)
        array[s]=new int [1];
    return array;
}

int main() {
    int **array;
//Тут читаем n и m из файла
    int m = 10;
    int n = 10;
    array = create_array(n,m);
    delete_array(array, m);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Отлично. Огромнейшее спасибо. Я даже не подумал, что выделяю не то что-то.
А второе то, что я не передаю сам массив в функцию delete_array - случайность, не то скопировал.

Answer (score 1):

Если не ошибаюсь, delete [] array; - нужно указать один раз в функции, чтобы удалить массив указателей. А в цикле вы удаляете все указатели массива.

Comment: @Infum, это-то (удаление в цикле) как раз правильно. 

Вы бы уже данный @KoVadim  ответ сначала прочли.